# In c#, how to combine strings and their frequency to a resulting string?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I know that we can find duplicate items like this:

```
var dublicateItems = itemStrings.GroupBy(x => x)
                                .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

And distinct items like this:

```
var distinctItems = itemStrings.Distinct();
```

But how to combine it to the following list of string:

input: `a, b, b, c, d, d, d, d`

output: `a, b (2 times), c, d (4 times)`

Comment: What is item strings exactly? `itemStrings.GroupBy(x => x)` sounds like it does what you want it to

Comment: `.ToDictionary(...).ToList()` is causing me physical pain

Comment: @Rawling Sorry, just edit them

Comment: @Anatoly Hehe, sorry, that wasn't very constructive of me. It's just something I've never seen before!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
var duplicateItems = 
  itemStrings
  .GroupBy(i => i)
  .Select(i => new { Key = i.Key, Count = i.Count() })
  .Select(i => i.Key + (i.Count > 1 ? " (" + i.Count + " times)" : string.Empty));
```

If you want the result as a comma-separated string, you can then do this:

```
var result = string.Join(", ", duplicateItems);
```

Comment: You're almost there; you have some spacing and comma issues

Comment: I'd remove the final `.ToList()`, and wrap the whole right side of the `=` in a `string.Join(" ", ...)` to give him what he's looking for.

Comment: @krillgar Well, it's not clear whether the OP wants a single comma separated string or a list of strings. But I'll add that option, okay.

Comment: @Luaan You add a trailing space if the item only appears once... but yeah, the commas aren't an issue if you're selecting a list rather than a single string

Comment: @Rawling Duh, I'm an idiot :D Trailing spaces aren't easy to see in output... :D

Comment: @Luaan The title of the question is to convert it to a single string. The question includes a section showing how the output should be formatted.

Comment: @krillgar You're right about the title. I wouldn't draw any conclusions from the output formatting, though - after all, the OP formatted the input the same way, even though it's supposed to be a string array. That's what got me confused :)

Comment: No worries. I was writing an answer that was virtually identical to yours, only with that string.Join when I saw yours pop up.

Answer (score 2):

You have  already the solution with the first approach, remove the `Where`

```
var itemCounts = itemStrings.GroupBy(x => x)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

string result = String.Join(", ", 
    itemCounts.Select(kv => kv.Value > 1 
        ? string.Format("{0} ({1} times)", kv.Key, kv.Value) 
        : kv.Key));
```

Another approach is using `Enumerable.ToLookup` instead of `GroupBy`:

```
var itemLookup = itemStrings.ToLookup(x => x);
string result = String.Join(", ",
     itemLookup.Select(grp => grp.Count() > 1 
         ? string.Format("{0} ({1} times)", grp.Key, grp.Count())
         : grp.Key));
```

Answer (score 1):

With something like:

```
string[] itemStrings = new[] { "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d" };
string[] duplicateItems = (from x in itemStrings.OrderBy(x => x).GroupBy(x => x)
                           let cnt = x.Count()
                           select cnt == 1 ? 
                                  x.Key : 
                                  string.Format("{0} ({1} times)", x.Key, cnt)
                          ).ToArray();
```

I've added an `OrderBy()` because your list seems to be ordered, and I've overcomplicated it a little just to cache the `x.Count()` (the `let cnt = x.Count()`) .

If you then want a single big string, you can

```
string joined = string.Join(",", duplicateItems);
```

Comment: Using `let` is a lot nicer, you're right. I haven't really used it as much as it deserves to be used :))